# Running a program from memory

Tags: c++, memory, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

If have a binary file that i read in a buffer. How can i run this file by injecting it's data in a random process?

I tried the following pathway:

1. Reading the file in char[]
2. Get a process's handle
3. Reserve virtual memory in this process equal to the file length via 
   VirtualAllocEx
4. Write the binary content to allocated virtual memory in this process
5. Creating a thread that runs from the entry point of the binary file.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>

IMAGE_DOS_HEADER        image_dos_header;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS        image_nt_headers;
PCHAR pMem;


using namespace std;
int getfile(const char * name, char ** ret=0)
{
FILE * pFile=new FILE;
long size;

pFile = fopen (name,"rb");

fseek (pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
size=ftell (pFile);
rewind(pFile);

if(ret)

{
    char *buffer;
    buffer = new char [size];
    // read data as a block:
    fread(buffer,1,size,pFile);
    *ret=buffer;
}

fclose (pFile);

return size;
}
int main()
{

DWORD PID=2356;
DWORD j;
char *buffer;
int filelen=getfile("understanding.exe",&buffer);//filename //#1


int virLen = filelen;

HANDLE hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,PID);//#2
if(hprocess != 0)
{
    LPVOID lpviraddr = VirtualAllocEx(hprocess,NULL,virLen,MEM_COMMIT|              MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);//#3
    if (lpviraddr != 0)
    {
        BOOL k = WriteProcessMemory(hprocess,lpviraddr,buffer,filelen,&j);
        if (k != 0)//#4
        {




            CreateRemoteThread(hprocess,NULL,0,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(lpviraddr+0xA8),NULL,0,NULL);//#5





        }
        else
        {
            std::cout <<GetLastError();
            printf("[*]Something Wrong - Operation Aborted1\n");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("[*]Something Wrong - Operation Aborted2\n");
    }

}
else
{

    std::cout <<GetLastError();
    printf("[*]Something Wrong - Operation Aborted3\n");
}




return 0;
}
```

The value `0xA8` is an offset where is located the entry point in the file.

The problem seems to be in the last step because it leads to the crashing of the host process without executing my file.

Comment: Check error codes! (and use a debugger)

Comment: It's not that easy... you'd have to emulate the whole work of the loader (load at the right address, read the dependencies, load them in the correct order, fix up the relocations, setup the required environment as required by the PE headers, ...) by hand (and not all of it is going to be possible from user mode - e.g. if the hosted code is calling - say `GetModuleFileName` the OS will return wrong stuff, because it looks up in its own data structures, which you cannot alter). You should really explain better what you are up to.

Comment: what i'm simply trying to do is injecting some file's code into a process.
ِ

Comment: Injecting a DLL [has some techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection), did you try some basic searches?

Comment: Portable executables generally won't work this way. They have to have their addresses relocated among other things. If it's a DLL, it's designed to be loaded at run-time and will make your life a million times easier.

Comment: It is operating system specific

Comment: If that code you are injecting works with relative addresses only and can find the functions it needs (if any) without the need of a formal IAT or stuff like that, it should work smoothly. Some long time ago i wrote a piece of code in pure assembly that did that, it would scan memory to find some window's functions (like GetProcAddress and LoadLibrary) to create its own IAT and then run like any other program. Could you provide any code for the program you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

The process of mapping a file directly, fixing it up so it is a (semi-)valid PE file and then running it is commonly referred to as `ManualMapping`.
I believe this term is coined by `Darawk`, who also wrote one of the very first (public) samples that did this.
Do note however, that his implementation lacks some (much needed) features.

There are samples floating around that are more complete, 
one of the more complete (and well tested) samples is:
https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/tree/master/src/BlackBone/ManualMap

Please note, this is meant to be ran from a driver, so there is some driver-related code surrounding it.